# Cannot install Flask or Pyodbc

Tags: python, flask, cmd, pip, pyodbc

I am making a python project in VS2017 which requires flask and pyodbc. At first I was running Python 3.8 and had no issues installing these two with pip, but in VS I was getting the error that "debugging is not supported for python 2.5 and earlier". People told me the solution to this would be to install an earlier version of Python. Many recommended version 3.5. So I uninstalled 3.8 and installed 3.5 (same path). The problem is that now I can no longer install pyodbc and flask. When I run pip install for both I am getting this long error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\python35\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Marc8\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hr1u7o04\\pyodbc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Marc8\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hr1u7o04\\pyodbc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Marc8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-i6_lvn4p\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python35\Include\pyodbc'
     cwd: C:\Users\Marc8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hr1u7o04\pyodbc\
Complete output (7 lines):
c:\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'pyodbc' extension
error: [WinError 2]
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'

Your `setuptools` is too old. To upgrade:

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

Perhaps you also need to upgrade `pip`:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```